# Bind to object from within ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, telerik

In an WPF window I am populating an RadComboBox (but same problem with a normal Combobox) with a static source. Works fine.

Now i want to check each element against an object from outside the ComboboxItem. I wrote an Multivalue-Converter (which works fine too) taking the object from the combobox item and the ne owned by the WPF window.

In the combobox i have Task-Types and the main object is called Task.

Point 1: Using `<Binding Path=""/>` I do get the combobox-item - but is this correct?

Point 2 (and the one i cant figure out): **How do i get up to the object Task owned by the WPF form?**

The Windows DataContext is set by `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

The Task object lies (for now) in code behind as:

```
private Task task;
public Task Task
{
    get { return this.task; }
    set
    {
        this.task = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged("Task");
    }
 }
```

This is my combobox:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="6,6,6,2" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource applicationBase}, Path=TaskTypes.TaskTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Task.TaskType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Touch" FontSize="16" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabledState, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBoxItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
        <Setter.Value>
          <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterTaskTypeEnabled}">
            <Binding Path=""/>
            <Binding Path="Task" />
          </MultiBinding>
        </Setter.Value>
       </Setter> 
     </Style>
   </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a good night sleep i found out myself how to solve this:

```
<telerik:RadComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  Margin="6,6,6,2" Padding="10,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource applicationBase}, Path=TaskTypes.TaskTypes}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Task.TaskType, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Touch" FontSize="16" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=IsEnabledState, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:RadComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ConverterTaskTypeEnabled}">
                        <Binding Path="."/>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}" Path="Task.TaskCategoryId" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter> 
        </Style>
    </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Binding to Path=. gets the item itself

By using the Window which owns the DataContext with the required second object as RelativeSource for my MultiConverter, i do get what i want and everything works like charm.